# C++ avoid full shift in bit operation

Tags: c++, bit

```
template<class _Diff,
        class _Urng>
        class _Rng_from_urng
    {   // wrap a URNG as an RNG
    public:
        explicit _Rng_from_urng(_Urng& _Func)
            : _Ref(_Func), _Bits(CHAR_BIT * sizeof(_Udiff)), _Bmask(_Udiff(-1))
        {   // construct from URNG
            for (; (_Urng::max)() - (_Urng::min)() < _Bmask; _Bmask >>= 1)
                --_Bits;
        }

        _Diff operator()(_Diff _Index)
        {   // adapt _Urng closed range to [0, _Index)
            for (;;)
            {   // try a sample random value
                _Udiff _Ret = 0;    // random bits
                _Udiff _Mask = 0;   // 2^N - 1, _Ret is within [0, _Mask]

                while (_Mask < _Udiff(_Index - 1))
                {   // need more random bits
                    _Ret <<= _Bits - 1; // avoid full shift
                    _Ret <<= 1;
                    _Ret |= _Get_bits();
                    _Mask <<= _Bits - 1;    // avoid full shift
                    _Mask <<= 1;
                    _Mask |= _Bmask;
                }

                // _Ret is [0, _Mask], _Index - 1 <= _Mask, return if unbiased
                if (_Ret / _Index < _Mask / _Index
                    || _Mask % _Index == _Udiff(_Index - 1))
                    return (_Ret % _Index);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The above code is pasted from stl. What the "avoid full shift" means? I think the two bit shift can be intecoplated into single operation.

```
_Ret <<= _Bits - 1; // avoid full shift 
_Ret <<= 1;
```

I change the codes as:

```
_Ret<<=_Bits;
```

What differs here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### [[expr.shift]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift#1)

> #### 7.6.7 Shift operators
>
> 1. The shift operators << and >> group left-to-right.
>
>    shift-expression:
>
>    additive-expression
>
>    shift-expression << additive-expression
>
>    shift-expression >> additive-expression
>
>    The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. **The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand**.

Comment: I. e. the shift is split into two ones to avoid undefined behaviour in case of `_Bits` being equal to `sizeof(_Udiff)*CHAR_BIT`, which might happen if the for loop in constructor is *not* entered.